# Загрузка javascript с помощью ajax

Tags: ajax, javascript

Сказали сделать `ajax`, который будет подгружать `js` скрипт в теге, не сам файл `.js`, а скрипт, вставленный в страницу, и чтобы ява скрипт потом работал. Как это можно сделать? Причем библиотеки использовать нельзя.

Answer (score 2):

Вариант без eval, суть мы просто при загрузке создаем тег скрипт, который и выполнится

```
var scriptEl = document.createElement('script');
scriptEl.src = url // url = то ссылка на скрипт
document.body.appendChild(scriptEl);
```

Лучше поместить в начале `body` ( не в `head`, так как тогда еще `body` не будет )
Если помещаете в `head`, то вместо `document.body`, надо будет написать `document.head`

Comment: А ничего что вопросу 3 года, мистер археолог?

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то необходимо исполнить чистый js код на клиенте.
Тогда задача состоит из двух подзадача:

1. Скачать скрипт с сервер
2. Исполнить скрипт

**Скачивание скрипта.**

Используем [xmlhttprequest](http://xmlhttprequest.ru/)

```
// Кросбраузерный вариант создания запроса
function getXmlHttp(){
  var xmlhttp;
  try {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  } catch (e) {
    try {
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (E) {
      xmlhttp = false;
    }
  }
  if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  return xmlhttp;
}

// теперь сам запрос
var xmlhttp = getXmlHttp()
xmlhttp.open('GET', '/xhr/test.js', true); // где /xhr/test.js - адрес скрипта
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
     if(xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        eval( '(' + xmlhttp.responseText + ')');
     }
  }
};
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

**Исполнение скрипта**

Обратите внимание на строчку

```
eval( '(' + xmlhttp.responseText + ')');
```

eval - метод исполняющий скрипт, подробнее [тут](http://javascript.ru/eval)

Comment: eval - зло, лучше просто скрипт аппендить в боди и он выполнится

Comment: Согласен. Но было лень писать её вставку без jquer